# Running a jersey project from command line

Tags: java, jersey

I have created a RESTful API using jersey that serves some GET endpoints. The thing though is that now I have to ship this project as  github link and provide instructions to open and run the project from the command line. I completely build the project using Eclipse and have scoured the web for resources but have no clue as to how to get this done. Could someone care to download the project into their machines and help with instructions to run it from the command line. The README has the links to the public endpoints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without needing to actually deploy it your Tomcat instance, you can use the [tomcat maven plugin](http://tomcat.apache.org/maven-plugin-trunk/tomcat7-maven-plugin/) (which is meant for development). It starts an embedded tomcat instance, so you can test your webapps. Just add the following to your pom.xml file

```
<build>
    <finalName>SimpleRestApi</finalName>
    <plugins>
        ...
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <path>/</path>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Then from the command line you can just run

```
mvn tomcat7:run
```

And a server instance will start. You can then access

```
http://localhost:8080/api/courses
```

If you want to change the context path, just use `<path>/SimpleRestApi</path>`. Then you can access

```
http://localhost:8080/SimpleRestApi/api/courses
```